# How to get an element from an array using index inside template?

Tags: ember.js

```
    {{#each compareDataRaw as |row index|}}
      {{log compareDesigns.[index]}}

      {{rr/bar-chart
        chartId=(concat "chart" index)
        data=row
      }}
    {{end}}
```

I am trying to get the element from `compareDesigns` array with no luck?

I have also tried snippet below with the same context  with the same outcome `undefined`.

```
{{log compareDesigns.index}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [get helper](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers.html#method_get)

```
{{get compareDesigns (concat index) }}
```

Comment: compareDesigns is an array. I think i need a custom helper instead

Comment: we need to pass string so using concat helper to convert it.. try my updated one

Comment: It does not work. It converts the entire array into a huge string. I do not think `get` works for an array.

Comment: check in this [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/1c15b60d894c00ff67c3b69bb130938c?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2C) its working for array of string and for array of object too

Comment: Yes, your solution did work. [Twitter](https://ember-twiddle.com/7d47ba804a8424f1976d45cac3d4c0f5?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2C). Then there must be something wrong with the data. Thanks

Comment: @XinyangLi just now noted you said Twitter instead of Twiddle  :-)

Comment: after 10 months?

Comment: yes someone upvoted this answer and came here to see the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have also created my own custom helper. (Not sure if this is redundant)

```
ember g helper array-at
```

Inside the `array-at.js` file,

import Ember from 'ember';

```
export function arrayAt(params/*, hash*/) {
  const arr = params[0];
  const index = params[1];
  return arr[index];
}

export default Ember.Helper.helper(arrayAt);
```

Inside the template file,

```
{{#each compareDataRaw as |row index|}}
  {{array-at compareDesigns index}}

  {{rr/bar-chart
    data=row
  }}
{{/each}}
```